# 'ticker' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Will be removed in Flame v1.9, use createTicker() instead

Tags: flutter, animation, sprite, ticker, flame

Warning of deprecation :
package:flame/src/sprite_animation.dart SpriteAnimationTicker ticker()
Containing class: SpriteAnimation
Returns a new instance of SpriteAnimationTicker

ticker() method is depreciated and will be removed in Flame v1.9,
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace your ticker() method as given example:

> animation : Returns the current [SpriteAnimation].

```
animation?.ticker().completed;
```

with:

```
animation?.createTicker().completed;
```